# Problem in understanding angular components

Tags: angular, ionic4

**I have a problem understanding angular components.**

I'm working on an ionic application and trying to make a simple app where i have a single component -as i supposed- that will be shown into different pages but will not be presented in the same form, but not all it's functionalities are common -i also know about ngtemplateoutlets and how i can pass the UI structure from outside or even made more than one template-.

**There are two use cases where the list component should be displayed**

**Case 1:** meta data should be shown: list name, short description and total items inside list.

In this case i have to implement onSelect, onEdit...etc.

**Case 2:** meta data should be shown: list name and list parent name.

In this case i have to implement only one function which is onSelect.

**So what i'm getting confused about :** should this be a one component or two as they will not be the same look and they are having different functionalities.

**But they are sharing the same object so i`m very confused about that**

Comment: Two of the options are fine. Choose the one your code will be the most readable

Comment: What do you recommend?

Comment: I personally would split this into 2 components. They would use Services so logic will not be double. And use generic functions to not replace HTML templates. But this would some times be an overkill

Comment: Best option is to create a base list component and 2 detail list components that extend them. Eg; BaseList, EditableList, DetailList